# Running updatedb fails with UnknownExtensionException error

Tags: updating

I am attempting to update my site's database after updating three modules: Configuration Update Base, Search API, and Simple XML Sitemap. Running drush updatedb produces the following error:

```
Drupal\Core\Extension\Exception\UnknownExtensionException: The module devel_generate_example does not exist. [error]in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php:265
Stack trace:#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ExtensionList.php(579):
Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->get('devel_generate_...')
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/core/includes/update.inc(318):
Drupal\Core\Extension\ExtensionList->checkIncompatibility('devel_generate_...')
#2 /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.12/libexec/commands/core/drupal/update.inc(134): update_get_update_list()
#3 /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.12/libexec/commands/core/core.drush.inc(462): update_main()
#4 /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.12/libexec/includes/command.inc(422): drush_core_updatedb()
#5 /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.12/libexec/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#6 /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.12/libexec/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command()
#7 /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.12/libexec/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch(Array)
#8 /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.12/libexec/includes/preflight.inc(66):
Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#9 /usr/local/Cellar/drush/8.1.12/libexec/drush.php(12): drush_main()
#10 {main}
```

I have confirmed that Devel and all of its submodules (including devel_generate and devel_generate_example) are installed. I have attempted deactivating, uninstalling, and reinstalling them, but I am still getting the same error. Does this look familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal can't find the module when it's scanning the codebase. You'll have to debug to figure out *why*. Run `drush eval 'print_r(array_map(function ($ext) { return $ext->subpath; }, \Drupal::service("extension.list.module")->getList()));'` to have Drupal dump what *modules it can see* and try see why it can't find the install location location (file permissions?).

Comment: Thanks! I ran your drush command, and devel_generate is on the list, so I'm still not sure why it's not finding devel_generate_example, which is a submodule of devel_generate. I have another Drupal site with a nearly identical configuration that is not having this problem, so hopefully some comparisons will help shed some light.

Comment: OK, this has actually turned out to be a larger issue with my site, unrelated to the Devel module. For some reason, I need to have ```settings['extension_discovery_scan_tests'] = TRUE;``` in ```settings.php``` in order to successfully run the update script. This is usually only set in ```settings.local.php```. I'm not sure why this Drupal installation needs to be able to locate all the testing submodules in order to update. The mystery continues!